# Changing the orientation of objects in a drop down menu from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, menu, orientation

Alright, so [my site](http://www.bassnbeats.com) has the bottom menu (the small greyed out plus sign) which I'd like the change the orientation of the objects that drop down from the menu from vertical to horizontal. Someone told me that I need to edit some of the parts in the toggle.js file, seen below. Also, if anyone has any ideas on how to make that plus I mentioned earlier darker, that'd be great too.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

// Submenu highlighting
$("ul.sub-menu").closest("li").addClass('parent');
$(".main-navigation ul.children").closest("li").addClass('parent');

var $comments = $( '#content' );

// Toggle comments on
$( '.comments-link' ).unbind( 'click' ).click( function() {

    $( 'html,body' ).animate( { scrollTop: $( "#comments-toggle" ).offset().top },'slow' );
    $comments.find( '#comments' ).slideToggle( 'ease' );
    $( this ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );

} );

var $sidebar = $( '#main' );

// Toggle sidebar on
$( '.sidebar-link' ).unbind( 'click' ).click( function() {
    $( 'html,body' ).animate( { scrollTop: $( "#secondary" ).offset().top },'slow' );
    $sidebar.find( '#secondary' ).slideToggle( 'ease' );
    $( this ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );

} );

//Toggle the the main navigation menu for small screens.
var $masthead = $( '#masthead' ),
    timeout = false;

$.fn.smallMenu = function() {
    $masthead.find( '.site-navigation' ).removeClass( 'main-navigation' ).addClass( 'main-small-navigation' );
    $masthead.find( '.site-navigation h1' ).removeClass( 'assistive-text' ).addClass( 'menu-toggle' );

    $( '.menu-toggle' ).unbind( 'click' ).click( function() {
        $masthead.find( '.menu' ).slideToggle( 'ease' );
        $( this ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
    } );
};

// Check viewport width on first load.
if ( $( window ).width() < 600 )
    $.fn.smallMenu();

// Check viewport width when user resizes the browser window.
$( window ).resize( function() {
    var browserWidth = $( window ).width();

    if ( false !== timeout )
        clearTimeout( timeout );

    timeout = setTimeout( function() {
        if ( browserWidth < 600 ) {
            $.fn.smallMenu();
        } else {
            $masthead.find( '.site-navigation' ).removeClass( 'main-small-navigation' ).addClass( 'main-navigation' );
            $masthead.find( '.site-navigation h1' ).removeClass( 'menu-toggle' ).addClass( 'assistive-text' );
            $masthead.find( '.menu' ).removeAttr( 'style' );
        }
    }, 200 );
} );
```

} );

This is the widget section of the page's CSS:

```
/* =Widgets
----------------------------------------------- */

.sidebar-link {
background: #fafafa;
border-radius: 40px;
clear: both;
color: #ddd;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-size: 18px;
font-size: 1.8rem;
line-height: 40px;
margin: 2em auto 0;
text-align: center;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-link:hover {
background-color: #444;
color: #969696;
transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.widget {
font-family: Baskerville, "Playfair Display", "Times New Roman", serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-size: 1.6rem;
font-weight: 100;
margin: 0 0 3em;
word-break: break-word;
}
.widget-column {
width: 100%;
}
.widget-title {
font-size: 24px;
font-size: 2.4rem;
margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
}
.one.widget-column {
float: none;
margin: 0 33%;
}
.two.widget-column {
float: left;
margin: 0 13.5%;
}
.three.widget-column {
float: left;
margin: 0 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you need to edit any JavaScript. Just modify your CSS for that menu. Here's a starting point:

```
#secondary .widget-column {
    width: 100%;
}

#secondary .widget {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm looking through the CSS now, original post will be edited with the widget section if you could take a look and make any more specific suggestions, as I have only been able to extend the area they can take up, but not their orientation.

Comment: Can you add the suggested `width` and `float` properties to the `.widget` block?

Comment: Well goddamn, that seems to have worked perfectly. I just had to stop being stupid for a second. Thanks a ton!